# Zip file not publish through a cake script in App Center

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, hockeyapp

I have moved my application from hockeyapp to app center

I am trying to publish a zip file to app center through a cake script for an Xamarin.Forms for UWP application. But the log shows no issues, but the file is not getting published. The below is the code I use to publish the zip file.

```
AppCenterDistributeRelease(new AppCenterDistributeReleaseSettings
{

       File = $"../AppDemo.UWP/AppPackages/AppPackages_{revisionName}.app.zip",

       DisableTelemetry = true,

       Version = true,

       Token ="my secret code",

       Group = "Collaborators",

       ReleaseNotesFile = $"../cireports/releasenotes/releasenotes.txt",

       App = "xamarincore/XF-SB-UWP-CI-1"

});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is related to the 3rd party App Center cake plugin. Finally, I published my application in the command prompt using the App Center CLI.

```
StartProcess("cmd.exe", new ProcessSettings{ Arguments = "/c appcenter distribute release --token ********* -f AppPackages.app.zip -g All-users-TestApp -R ../releasenotes.txt --app User/TestApp -b " +version});
```